# Send audio from ReactMediaRecorder to a server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, xmlhttprequest, blob

I'm trying to program a Client, that can record audio data and then send it to a server.

I don't have much experience in front-end development. I was told to use React and so I'm trying to use ReactMediaRecorder (https://github.com/avasthaathraya/react-media-recorder).

```
  render () {
        return (
            <ReactMediaRecorder
                audio
                whenStopped={blobUrl=>this.setState({audio: blobUrl })}
                render={({startRecording, stopRecording, mediaBlob }) => (
                    <div>
                        <button id="recorder" className="button" onClick={startRecording}>Start Recording</button>
                        <button className="button" onClick={() => {stopRecording();this.upload()}}>Stop Recording</button>
                        <audio id="player" src={mediaBlob} controls />
                    </div>
                )}
            />
        )
    }



    upload() {
        console.log("upload was called with blob " + this.state.audio)
        //if (false) {
        if (this.state.audio != null) {
            console.log("got here, type of audio is " + this.state.audio)


            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var filename = new Date().toISOString();
            xhr.onload = function (e) {
                if (this.readyState === 4) {
                    console.log("Server returned: ", e.target.responseText);
                }
            };
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append("audio_data", this.state.audio, filename);
            xhr.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:3000", true);
            xhr.send(fd);
        }
    }
```

At first it seemed very straightforward. But I don't get why I can't send the mediaBlob. The `formData.append` says, that `this.state.audio` is not of type `Blob`. So I checked it's type in the console log, and found out it is of type `stringContent`. I tried to create a Blob from that by using `new Blob()` but failed. I also fail to find information of this type.

Does somebody know what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finally got it. The mistake was, that `mediaBlob` is actually not blob, but a blob Url. So first we need to load it and then we can send it. I changed my upload function to:

```
upload(mediaBlob) {
    if (this.state.audio != null) {
        //load blob
        var xhr_get_audio = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr_get_audio.open('GET', mediaBlob, true);
        xhr_get_audio.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr_get_audio.onload = function(e) {
            if (this.status == 200) {
                var blob = this.response;
                //send the blob to the server
                var xhr_send = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var filename = new Date().toISOString();
                xhr_get_audio.onload = function (e) {
                    if (this.readyState === 4) {
                        console.log("Server returned: ", e.target.responseText);
                    }
                };
                var fd = new FormData();
                fd.append("audio_data",blob, filename);
                xhr_send.open("POST", "http://localhost/uploadAudio", 
                true);
                xhr_send.send(fd);
            }
        };
        xhr_get_audio.send();
    }
}
```

Now it works fine.